# oracle - Change host to 0.0.0.0 in listener

Tags: oracle-12c, listener

Im using oracle 12c on windows server 2016. I want to make my oracle to listen to the port 1521 to 0.0.0.0

Here is my listner.ora file.

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\bhuvi\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_ORCL_BHUVI =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\bhuvi\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\bhuvi\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

ORCL_BHUVI =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

You can see the HOST is 0.0.0.0, but when I start the listener, there it listening the port 1521 to localhost (my hostname is bhuvi-oracle)

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 18-APR-2020 17:29:19

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                18-APR-2020 17:29:12
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 9 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\bhuvi\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\bhuvi\virtual\diag\tnslsnr\bhuvi-oracle\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=bhuvi-oracle)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: It can be done but instance will be isolated no users cannot connect through network unless they have direct access to host server or via ssh.Why 0.0,0.0?.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve with this "0.0.0.0" configuration?

Comment: I have some applications which are connecting from outside.  Im not able to access it.

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0  -- Sounds like you may not be clear on what the `HOST =` parm for the TNS Listener is for.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the files at the following locations:

1. `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora`
2. `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`

On both these files you have to update the `HOST` attribute to `0.0.0.0`

Restart both the Oracle database and listener after making these changes.

Hope this helps anyone else stuck on this issue.